# VMWare to Physical Machine - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, vmware-converter, v2p

Is it possibly (for example) to build a Virtual Machine, with windows 7, and then port this to a physical machine..?

For example, build up a configuration of a machine in virtual machine, then deploy this to a physical machine, so that it basically installs all the software on to the target machine, without running it as a VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it can be a bit of a headache, [HERE](http://www.vmware.com/support/v2p/index.html) is how VMWare recommend you do it.

Answer (score 0):

yes. Build your VM, capture it with a disk imaging solution (WinPE/WIM for instance) and deploy your image to a physical computer. Or you can (I believe) use VMWare Converter to do V2P conversions.

Bear in mind though, that you *might* run into driver difficulties, but the risks here are way lower than they were on previous OSes.

Give it a go!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if being able to do a virtual-to-physical installation with only freely available tools was a requirement or not, but you could do something like this using Acronis TrueImage with Universal Restore.

TrueImage allows one to make an image of the system drive and install it to multiple machines (and supports changing of SIDs, etc).

Universal Restore (which is an extension to TrueImage) allows one to install an image to a machine with different hardware (and specify drivers requried for the different hardware).

Unfortunately, both of these are paid software and not freely available ones.